# Functional Equation f(x) = f(x/2)

Tags: functions, contest-math, functional-equations

> Find all functions $f$ satisfying the property that
>   $$
> f(x) = f(x/2)
> $$
>   for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$

So far I've come up with the following assumptions:

-$f$ is periodic, i.e of form $f(x) = A \cos(g(x))$

-$O(g(x)) = \log_2x$

I've hit a dead end though. Are my assumptions correct? What else should I try?

EDIT: Here's the motivation behind the periodicity:[image: Sinusoid]

Comment: I like that you could realize it is periodic... but why only $A\cos (g(x))$? what would be other possibilities?

Comment: You say it is contest math so please tell us where did you find this exercise.

Comment: https://www.math.wisc.edu/wiki/index.php/Putnam_Club. It's from the 'Functions and Calculus' pdf. I'm not sure if it's an actual Putnam problem, but I stumbled upon this site and thought it looked fun.

Comment: Constant functions should be included as well, trivially.

Comment: I think there's an implicit assumption of continuity here; otherwise, I don't think the set of functions defined has a better characterisation than the equation giving in the problem.

Comment: Trivially, there is the constant function $f(x)=c$.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint** $f(x)=f({x\over 2})=f({x\over 2^2})=\dots=f({x\over 2^n})$

If $f$ is continuous then $f(x)=f(0)$

Comment: The constant solution came to mind, but I want to think there's more to this problem... I uploaded an image of what I had in mind. I can't think of a way to construct it, but the idea is that its period approaches $0$ as $x \rightarrow \infty$, similar to $f(x) = \cos(1/x)$

Answer (score 2):

Let $X_n$ denote every interval in the form $[2^n, 2^{n+1})$ (Which means $\cup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} X_n =\mathbb{R}_+^*$ and $X_n \cap X_m = \emptyset$ whenever $n \neq m$). Further, define the equivalence relation $\sim$ by $x \sim y\ \Leftrightarrow \ x=2^n y$, for some $n \in \mathbb{Z}$. Now, take any function $g:X/\sim\  \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, and define $f_1:\mathbb{R}_+^* \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ by $$f_1(x):=g([x])$$ ($[x]:=\{2^n x \in \mathbb{R} | n\in \mathbb{Z}\}$). That the above implies the initial condition is trivial (since $x \sim x/2$). If $f(x)=f(x/2)$ for every $x$, then $f(x)=f(2^n x)$, for every $n \in \mathbb{Z}$, which means the value of $f(x)$ depends entirely on $[x]$ i.e. $f(x)=g([x])$, for some $g$.

Define $f_2$ analogously for the negative numbers, choose any number $k \in \mathbb{R}$ and impose $f_3(0)=k$. Then $$f=f_1 \cup f_2 \cup f_3$$ is clearly the most general solution.

As stated in the other answer, continuity implies $f=constant$